# Linq to sql partial update?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Is it possible to do a partial update through linq2sql?

If I want to update only 2 fields I would use sql like

```
update table set col1 = val1, col2 = val2 where id = @id
```

I find the "fetch it from database, change it and then update" process a bit, well ineffective, if not just weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ (Language Integrated **Query**) is for querying, not full CRUD. LINQ-to-SQL handles the Update, Delete, and Create actions via a typical object model.

Since you already have the ID of the object you want to update, we will assume you have that entity object in LINQ (e.g. `from item in table where id=1 select item`):

```
myItem.Col1 = "val1";
myItem.Col2 = "val2";

dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

This works for one-off updates where you have a specific record to change.

If, for some reason, you do not have the original entity object but have the ID, you can execute arbitrary SQL via the DataContext:

```
dataContext.ExecuteQuery(
    "UPDATE table SET col1={0}, col2={1} WHERE ID={3}", 
    value1,
    value2,
    id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can generate update statements without doing a fetch:

```
Foo foo=new Foo { FooId=fooId }; // create obj and set keys
context.Foos.Attach(foo);
foo.Name="test";
context.SubmitChanges();
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3351534/52817