# Save entity with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I'm saving entities/records with the EF, but i'm curious if there is another way of doing it.

I receive a class from a MVC controller method, so basicly i have all the info: the class's properties, including the primary key.
Without EF i would do a Sql update (update table set a=b, c=d where id = 5), but with EF i got no further than this:

Get an object with ID of 5 
Update the (existing) object with the new object
Submitchanges.

What bothers me is that i have to get the object from the database first, where i have all the info to do an update statement.

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: so you just dont like having to translate whatever you have to the entity object?

Comment: correct, now i'm typing ExistingPeson.Name = PostedPerson.Name etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the pattern is typically:

1. select the entity
2. Update the properties
3. Save your changes

[Another SO question on this topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445033/use-linq-to-generate-direct-update-without-select)

Answer (score -2):

```
u will have to create an object, update the properties and then savechanges 

try this 

using (var context = new NorthWindEntities())
{
    Product prod = new Product();
    prod.Name = "Car toy";
    prod.Price = "10.00";

    prod.SaveChanges();//this method will actuayll save the changes

}
```