# Can we write Update statement in linq?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

can we write update statement in linq?

example:

```
var query = Update customer set isEdit = 1 where id = 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't. The *Q* in LINQ stands for *Query*.

What you can do is the following:

```
foreach(var c in customer.Where(x => x.Id == 1))
    c.isEdit = 1;
```

Comment: In Linq To SQL, doesn't this function hit the database for each row?

Comment: @Scorpi0: Most likely, yes. But because the ID of a customer is probably a unique key this doesn't really matter because there only is one row.

Comment: I find this pretty dangerous for a beginner. Maybe customer.Where(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault() is more indicate for the OP.

Comment: @Scorpi0: That would have changed the meaning of the query.

Answer (score 3):

You can shortcut the updates by doing a 'looks like Linq' query, using the [ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bwabdf9z.aspx) method of the class [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6sh2ey19.aspx):

```
var toUpdate = customer.Where(c => c.id == 1).ToList();
toUpdate.ForEach(c => c.isEdit = 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3351534/52817).

```
Foo foo=new Foo { FooId=fooId }; // create obj and set keys
context.Foos.Attach(foo);
foo.Name="test";
context.SubmitChanges();
```

In your Dbml set UpdateCheck="Never" for all properties.

**This will generate a single update statement** without having to do a select first.